# SELECT COUNT() GROUP BY Set of data in IN() mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

My table is like

**Loves table (loves)**

```
animal_id | user_id | time
   1          1
   2          1 
   1          3
   1          5
   2          3 
   3          1
```

**Animals table(animal)**

```
id | type   |   name
 1     air       animal 1 
 2     ground    animal 2
 3     water     animal 3
 4     space     animal 4
 5     air       animal 5  
 6     ground    animal 6
```

**My Query**

```
( select count(*) from loves where animal_id = a.animal_id) as n_l,
 a.name 
FROM animal a ,loves lp 
WHERE a.animal_id =  lp.animal_id 
  AND lp.user_id = $MYUSERID  
  AND a.type IN ($MYANIMALTYPES) 
ORDER BY lp.time DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Now if `$MYUSERID = 1` and `$MYANIMALTYPES = 'air','ground'`

*I should get output as from above example*

```
n_l | name 
3     animal 1 
2     animal 2
```

But for some reason i want to get combinations of

`$MYANIMALTYPES = 'air','ground'` ,

`$MYANIMALTYPES = 'air','water'` ,

`$MYANIMALTYPES = 'space'`,

and

`$MYANIMALTYPES = 'space','water`

seperately in groups i have to run the above query 4 times for each `$MYANIMALTYPES`.

My problem is that I'm using too many queries for what i want. Is there any way to get what i want in **One single query** ?

**UPDATE**

*For a simple understanding how do i combine these **two** queries below into **one** query ?*

```
( select count(*) from loves where animal_id = a.animal_id) as n_l,
 a.name 
FROM animal a ,loves lp 
WHERE a.animal_id =  lp.animal_id 
  AND lp.user_id = $MYUSERID  
  AND a.type IN ('ground','air') 
ORDER BY lp.time DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

AND

```
( select count(*) from loves where animal_id = a.animal_id) as n_l,
 a.name 
FROM animal a ,loves lp 
WHERE a.animal_id =  lp.animal_id 
  AND lp.user_id = $MYUSERID  
  AND a.type IN IN ('air','space') 
ORDER BY lp.time DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: why was this downvoted ;(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question was well written. Sometimes you just have to ignore downvotes.

Comment: so whats the solution @OllieJones

Comment: I think you make two separated question. First your `IN` is working? then you want different groups in same query?

Comment: `$MYANIMALTYPES = 'air','ground'` is that a string csv? or one array?

Comment: see update @JuanCarlosOropeza and its a `array` converted to string using `join` to be able to  use in mysql statement

Comment: Why are you asking for a user_id but returning the number of loves over all users? Is that intentional?

Comment: So your `a.type IN ($MYANIMALTYPES)` Is working?

Comment: Note that in the *animal* table you have an *id* field, but in the query you address it as *animal_id*.

Comment: Maybe you can just take your basic query, make a view of it and then use UNION

Comment: Thanks everyone but i got my answer from @trincot exactly what i was looking for. I did few mistakes while writing the question so forgive me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this adaptation of your query. It adds a join to the 4 type combinations you are interested in:

```
SELECT      ( SELECT count(*)
              FROM   loves
              WHERE  animal_id = a.animal_id) as n_l,
            a.name,
            trim(concat(types.type1, ' ', types.type2)) grp
FROM        animal a 
INNER JOIN  loves lp 
         ON a.animal_id =  lp.animal_id  
INNER JOIN  ( SELECT 'air' type1, 'ground' type2
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'air', 'water'
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'space', ''
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'space', 'water' ) AS types
         ON a.type IN (types.type1, types.type2)
WHERE       lp.user_id = $MYUSERID
GROUP BY    a.name,
            trim(concat(types.type1, ' ', types.type2))
ORDER BY    3, lp.time DESC 
LIMIT 15
```

I also set the limit higher as you will now get all the results in one query.

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56ffa/1).

Comment: This is it! Your'e Genius!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cant use string directly

if you string is

```
  $MYANIMALTYPES = "'air','ground'"
```

That translate into

```
 a.type IN ('air,ground');
```

and you need

```
 a.type IN ('air', 'ground');
```

Try with `FIND_IN_SET`

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(a.type, @MYANIMALTYPES) > 0
```

Comment: No that's not the problem the query i gave is running fine. But i want to use only one query.